# Using Extensions Provided in Dart Packages

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to use the RootsExtension (https://pub.dev/documentation/data/latest/data.polynomial/RootsExtension.html) in the data.polynomial library in the data package (https://pub.dev/documentation/data/latest/), but I can't seem to be able to add the roots extension property to the Polynomial class to be able to do `polynomial.roots`.

I even imported the file where the extension is located using  `import 'package:data/src/polynomial/operator/roots.dart';`, but I still can't add the roots property to the Polynomial class.

```
import 'package:data/polynomial.dart';
import 'package:data/src/polynomial/operator/roots.dart'; //not even used

Polynomial polynomial = Polynomial<double>.fromCoefficients(
    DataType.float64, coeffs);
List<Complex> roots = polynomial.roots; //extension property, roots, not detected
```

Any help with applying extension to the Polynomial class will be much appreciated.

If you're curious what the extension file `roots.dart` looks like, it's like this:

```
library data.polynomial.operator.roots;

import ...

extension RootsExtension<T extends num> on Polynomial<T> {
     List<Complex> get roots {
          ...
          return rootsList;
     }
}
```

EDIT: It works now. It seems that I needed to specify the type of the polynomial variable better and needed to write `Polynomial<double> polynomial = Polynomial<double>.fromCoefficients....`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import [data packages](https://pub.dev/packages/data) first on your `pubspec.yaml` file. And then you only need to import this:

```
import 'package:data/polynomial.dart';
```

Or import other additional things based on this [installation guides](https://pub.dev/packages/data#-installing-tab-).

Comment: I don't have any trouble with importing the data package, I'm having trouble with using the extension feature to add more functionality to the Polynomial class

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because I didn't specify the type of the polynomial variable specific enough. I needed to do

`Polynomial<double> polynomial = Polynomial<double>.fromCoefficients( DataType.float64, coeffs);`